# shifting up the column basis groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id       event      time_spent_in_sec
A         in               0
A         step_1           2.2
A         step_2           3
A         done             3
B          in              0
B         step_1           5
B         step_2           8
B         step_3           15
B         done             7
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Id       event      time_spent_in_sec
A         in               2.2
A         step_1           3
A         step_2           3
A         done             0
B          in              5
B         step_1           8
B         step_2           15
B         step_3           7
B         done             0
```

I am looking to shift the value in a column **time_spent_in_sec** and fill last row of each unique Id by 0.

I tried using `shift(1)` but stuck with filling the last row with 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numpy.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
df['time_spent_in_sec'] = np.roll(df['time_spent_in_sec'], -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.fillna()` to fill it with the original first number:

```
df.time_spent_in_sec.shift(-1).fillna(df.time_spent_in_sec[0])
```

Or:

```
df.time_spent_in_sec.shift(-1, fill_value = df.time_spent_in_sec[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way to do it: Transforming into a list and shift if from there.

```
list_col = list(df["time_spent_in_sec"])
list_col.append(list_col.pop(0))
df["time_spent_in_sec"] = list_col.copy()
```